# Falcon LLM no output running on Azure Notebook

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers

I have been unable to get any output from the model even waiting 10 minutes. Running on a Azure Notebook with a Compute instance Standard_E4ds_v4, 4 core, 32GB.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Code:

```
!source activate llm_env

%pip install conda
import conda
%conda install cudatoolkit

%pip install torch
%pip install einops
%pip install accelerate
%pip install transformers==4.27.4
%pip install huggingface-hub
%pip install chardet
%pip install cchardet

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TFAutoModelForCausalLM
import transformers
import torch

model = "tiiuae/falcon-7b"
rrmodel = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model, 
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    device_map="auto",)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

input_text = "What is a giraffe?"
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors='pt')

attention_mask = torch.ones(input_ids.shape)
output = rrmodel.generate(input_ids, 
            attention_mask=attention_mask, 
            max_length=2000,
            do_sample=True,
            pad_token_id = 50256,
            top_k=10,
            num_return_sequences=1,
            eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,)
#Never goes into this section
print(f"Got output: {output}")
output_text = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

print(output_text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i believe was how i prompted the model, It is a text generation model so in my case i was giving a transcript and i had to write in the end "Summary: ".

So this **DID NOT** work: "Summarize this transcript. Transcript: ..."

This **WORKED**: "Transcript: .... , Summary: "

Full Working code below:

```
model_path="tiiuae/falcon-7b"

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_path, trust_remote_code=True)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, trust_remote_code=True, load_in_4bit=True, device_map="auto")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
input_text = "What is a giraffe?"
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to("cuda")
attention_mask = torch.ones(input_ids.shape)

outputs = model.generate(input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            max_length=2000,
            do_sample=True,
            top_k=10,
            num_return_sequences=1,
            eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,)

for output in outputs:
  output_text = tokenizer.decode(output, skip_special_tokens=True)
  print("GENERATED TEXT: ------------")
  print(output_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I changed the **max-length to 100** to check its run time.

I create a **VM size of 140GB** with **CPU** as below,

[image]

I made small changes with your code as below,

**Code:**

```py
import conda
%conda install cudatoolkit

%pip install torch
%pip install einops
%pip install accelerate
%pip install transformers==4.27.4
%pip install huggingface-hub
%pip install chardet
%pip install cchardet

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TFAutoModelForCausalLM
import transformers
import torch
print("Done1")

model = "tiiuae/falcon-7b"
rrmodel = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model, 
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    device_map="auto")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

print("Done2")
input_text = "What is a giraffe?"

input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors='pt')

attention_mask = torch.ones(input_ids.shape)
output = rrmodel.generate(input_ids, 
            attention_mask=attention_mask, 
            max_length=100,
            do_sample=True,
            pad_token_id = 50256,
            top_k=10,
            num_return_sequences=1,
            eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)

print(f"Got output: {output}")
output_text = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

print(output_text)
```

Then, I started running the code in my **ML Studio** like below,

[image]

[image]

[image]

It almost took **3:30 hrs** to run like below,

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

**With 100 max-length it took 3:30 hrs, it will take much time for 2000 max-length. Deploy the VM that runs your notebook with higher GPU size.**

Comment: Thank you for the effort and screenshots, i posted what i think was the solution below.